# std::chrono gives different value while used from main or from class method

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, c++-chrono

I have created utility class in c++ to be able to get the run time of different methods. I am trying to store time calculated using chrono in a struct so I can store all the methods I am using in the program, to be measured and printed at the end. The problem is, most of the time when I call that from another code it returns 0 as output, but if I use chrono.now to directly calculate elapsed time in main function, it gives actual output.

Below is how I have created the methods in c++ file to collect time from different functions (Header and cpp is different but I have declared struct in the cpp file directly):

Struct Declaration and initialization:

```cpp
struct analysis{
    const char * func_name;
    int calc_time;
    analysis(const char* x, const int y):
    func_name(x), calc_time(y){}
};
vector<analysis> time_coll {};
```

method to start storing the time:

```cpp
void Utility::tStart(){
      auto chrono_strt = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); 
      sink = chrono_strt;
}
```

method to store end time:

```cpp
void Utility::tEnd(const char* func_name){
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point chrono_stp = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); 
    std::chrono::microseconds elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(chrono_stp - sink);    
    time_coll.push_back((analysis(func_name, elapsed.count())));    
}
```

method to print the time at end:

```cpp
void Utility::pStat(){
    for( const auto& elem: time_coll){
        cout << elem.func_name  << " : " << elem.calc_time << endl;
    }
}
```

Sample of usage in other method:

```cpp
void Sort::BubbleSort(vector<int>& a){
    u.tStart();
    int temp;
    for (int i=0; i<=(a.size());i++){
        for(int j=0; j<=(a.size())-2;j++){
            if(a[j]>a[j+1]){
                temp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j+1];
                a[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }

    }
    u.tEnd(__FUNCTION__);
}
```

The above methods mostly produces 0 as outcome except that I give extremely large input to the function under inspection(I have tested it on bubble sort). When I call the chrono in main file from start to end (without using the above mentioned methods), I am getting correct outcome.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @n.m. Sorry about that I am new here, How do you want me to produce 'minimal reproducible example' of a code which can only be reproduced with multiple files ? I can share github link, but not sure if I am suppose to do that here.

Comment: Almost nothing in C++ requires multiple source files, certainly not this problem.

Comment: @n.m. Here's one file [Github one file] (https://github.com/trivedip/temp_for_git/blob/master/utility_temp.cpp) Output is :
main : 0
1106

Comment: You should know that benchmarking with `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` may not always do what you think. Depending on the platform, it is either an alias to `std::chrono::steady_clock` or, worse, an alias to `std::chrono::system_clock`. One should always use `std::chrono::steady_clock` for timing operations such as yours so that you are immune to the wall clock changing. Just imagine the results if you happened to benchmark across a time zone border or when DST adjustments are made =D Best advice is to just not use `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context it depends what you mean with an extremely large input. On modern computers, bubble sort will execute very fast, also for relatively large inputs. My suspicion is that the function executes too fast relative to your duration resolution (microseconds).

My advice would be not to cast the duration that is calculated by the clock, but to store it directly, something along the following lines (untested):

```
struct analysis {
  analysis(const char* x, const chrono::nanoseconds y) : func_name{x}, calc_time{y} {}

  string func_name;
  chrono::nanoseconds calc_time;
};

void Utility::tEnd(const char* func_name) {
  std::chrono::nanoseconds elapsed{chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - sink};    
  time_coll.emplace_back(func_name, elapsed);    
}
```

Then, when reporting the elapsed time, convert to microseconds at that time:

```
void Utility::pStat() {
  using FractionalUs = std::chrono::duration<double, std::micro>;
  for (const auto& elem: time_coll) {
    cout << elem.func_name  << " : " 
         << std::chrono::duration_cast<FractionalUs>(elem.calc_time).count() << "us\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: This did not solve my problem (Although your code works pretty flawlessly, Kudos to that!) , this as well as my solution both gives zero when I call the tStart and tEnd from another c++ file inside that function declaration,  but somehow works fine if I call tStart and tEnd around the function-call in driver file.

Comment: "....both gives zero when I call the tStart and tEnd from another c++ file inside that function declaration..." I don't understand this part. Can you give examples of the two separate ways in which `tStart` and `tEnd` are used?